# How to parse CET/CEST datetime?

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datetime

I got a JSON on the server, and I try to parse it. The problem is that some dates looks like:

```
Tue, 03 Sep 2013 12:18:45 CEST
```

some as:

```
Sat, 17 Nov 2012 15:39:43 CET
```

so if I do somethins like:

```
var processedData = DateTime.ParseExact((string)item.pubDate, "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss CEST", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

only on `CEST` dates it works, else it raises an exception.

How can I solve it? I hope `.Replace()` it is not the answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use **Multiple Formats** like:

```
string[] formats = new[] 
{
    "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss CEST",
    "ddd, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss CET"
};

var processedData = DateTime.ParseExact((string)item.pubDate,
                                    formats, 
                                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
                                    DateTimeStyles.None);
```

Comment: It says `'System.Globalization.CultureInfo' does not contain a definition for 'InvariantCulturee'`

Comment: @markzzz It is not `InvariantCulturee`, it is `InvariantCulture`. Delete unnecessary `e` at the end of.

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you boss!